# Tikz: Water marker inside cylinder

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have made a cylinder (in the horizontal position) as shown on the left. The cylinder is filled with water and I want to make a mark as shown on the right. How can I make this happen?
[image]
Here is the syntax for the left image.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[dvipnames]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill[cyan!60,opacity=.4] (-.54,-.97)--(3.46,-.97)--(4.68,-.39)--(.68,-.39);
            \draw[blue] (-.54,-.97)--(3.46,-.97)--(4.68,-.39);
            \draw[blue,dashed] (3.46,-.97)--(4.68,-.39)--(.68,-.39)--(-.54,-.97);
            \draw[thick] (0,0) circle (.7071 and 1.5);
            \draw[thick] (4,0) circle (.7071 and 1.5);
            \draw[thick] (0,-1.5)--(4,-1.5);
            \draw[thick] (0,1.5)--(4,1.5);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401630/how-can-i-fill-below-of-intersection-of-a-plane-and-a-cylinder-of-this-picture